# Response showing undefined in angular when subscribing observables

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have get method,which is fetching data from some `Api` and the response (I got this `JSON` data using postman) coming is:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "order_id": 6,
            "todayDate": "2020-07-04T15:09:40.556+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "order_id": 7,
            "todayDate": "2020-07-04T15:13:16.464+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "order_id": 8,
            "todayDate": "2020-07-05T13:41:13.337+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "order_id": 9,
            "todayDate": "2020-07-05T13:58:21.771+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "order_id": 10,
            "todayDate": "2020-07-05T14:03:07.791+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 5,
        "pageSize": 5,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalElements": 39,
    "totalPages": 8,
    "last": false,
    "size": 5,
    "number": 1,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 5,
    "first": false,
    "empty": false
}
```

So,normally while getting response from AJAX,I used to do, `console.log(res.content)` and it give me proper list of orders. But, in my service class in angular 9,I used interface to map the response,but it is not working.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CartItem } from '../common/cart-item';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Order } from '../common/order';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

  private baseUrl="http://localhost:8080/api/test";

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }


  getOrderDetails():Observable<Order[]>{
    const orderUrl=`${this.baseUrl}`+'/getAllPendingOrders';
    return  this.httpClient.get<GetResponseOrder>(orderUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response.content.orders)
       );
  }
  
}
interface GetResponseOrder {
  content :{
     orders :Order[];
    }
}
```

And I subscribed in myorder.component.ts as:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._cartService.getOrderDetails().subscribe((res) =>{
       console.log(res);
           
    }); 
  }
```

But,on my console,I see, `undefined` while trying to see the response.So, my `Order.ts` file is:

```
export class Order {
 
    order_id:Number;
     todayDate:Date;
    status:String;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related to your response, i think it should be

```
getOrderDetails():Observable<Order[]>{
 const orderUrl=`${this.baseUrl}`+'/getAllPendingOrders';
 return  this.httpClient.get<GetResponseOrder>(orderUrl).pipe(
   map(response => response.content)
   );
}
```

content is an array , i can't see orders, your interface becomes

```
interface GetResponseOrder {
 content : Order[];
}
```

Comment: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.